# ADG608 multiplexer acting really strange in Multisim

Tags: resistors, simulation, multiplexer, multimeter, multisim

I am trying to use the circuit below to switch between multiple resistors using a multiplexer. Initially I had different values of resistors attached to every channel, but since I was getting very strange and HUGE!! results, I grounded all the channels except the first channel and just connected a 120 ohm resistor. I am measuring resistor readings of magnitudes of Mega ohms and I have no idea how such huge values of resistance are showing up at all. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and I really really appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the enthusiasts on the national instruments forum answered my question and I would like to share that with everyone else too. It can be found on the following [link](http://forums.ni.com/t5/Circuit-Design-Suite/Odd-results-from-ADG608-multiplexer/td-p/3114675)